# Problemas con el gradle en cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

Estoy intentando arrancar un emulador de android en cordova y me da error.
Sale lo siguiente:

```
<Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal C:\gradle-4.0>
```

Yo hice nueva variable de entorno `PATH_GRADLE` y añadí la ruta de gradle a la variable "path". No entiendo por qué no lo encuentra.

Comment: Solo por confirmar. La variable es `path` y no `phat`

Comment: pues eso, pero no me lo encuentra

Comment: Digo, porque igual era un fallo tipográfico. Pero está bien si en tu ordenador tienes path, he actualizado la pregunta